# filtering autocomplete options in windows mobile app

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

i'm working on windows mobile app (c#, .net 2.0). i would like to make use of the device's autocomplete features for a specific textbox, but i want to be more specific than the device provides by default.

for example, i want to autocomplete to suggest a word of a specific length. it would also be nice to have several options given at once.

can anyone give me some help on this, or a link to helpful references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in autocomplete is, unfortunately, quite limited in capability.  It would be great if we had some form of callback or hook that we could use to intercept and alter its behavior, but there isn't.  The only way to get the granularity of control that you're after is to roll your own (or find a thrid-party) auto-complete control.